# Can added mass depend on stochasticity of motion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mass, inertia

Can [added mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Added_mass) (also called virtual mass or induced mass) of a voluminous object in a massive fluid surrounding be affected by some [stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic) motion of the mass (relative motion between the object and the surrounding)? Stochasticity is supposed to exist in all threes directions in 3D space and added mass is sought for unidirectional acceleration.

One coarse approach is just assuming some mean speed $\bar{v}$ in the surrounding medium. The average speed change $\Delta \bar{v}$ of the fluid close to the object will slow down and speed up surrounding fluid. On average the kinetic energy will vary as:

$$K(\bar{v}, \Delta{\bar{v}})=\frac{m/2(\bar{v}+\Delta \bar{v})^2+m/2(\bar{v}-\Delta \bar{v})^2}{2}=\frac{m(\bar{v}^2+(\Delta \bar{v})^2)}{2}$$

With this reasoning it seems like added mass is independent of stochasticity, but maybe a term should be added from the elastic collisions of the fluid on the object.